# how to process and append rows to existing excel worksheet in created workbook using node.js

Tags: node.js, excel, export, exceljs, sheetjs

i'm using node-pg-stream library to query large table and get the data at chunks using the readable stream that provided by this library, what i want to do is appending each received chunk into created workbook that contain specific worksheet, how to achieve such thing? could anyone give an example or any client library to do it?

snippet example:

```
const query = new QueryStream('select * from large_table');
    const stream = client.query(query);
    //release the client when the stream is finished
    stream.on('end', () => {
      done();
      //STREAM THE FILE TO CLIENT OR DO SOMETHING WHEN IT DONE 

    });
    stream.on('data', function (data) {
      
    //PAUSE THE STREAM  
    
      stream.pause();
      
      //HERE IS WHAT I WANT TO DO (APPEND THIS DATA TO EXISTING WORKSHEET INSIDE WORKBOOK)

      stream.resume();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The [node-xlsx](https://github.com/mgcrea/node-xlsx) project can work with `.xlsx` files in node.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this and i covered my solution on a medium article [here](https://medium.com/@ameerdhi7?p=2486f8f25184)